# Correct way to handle undefined declaration files (index.d.ts)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, node-modules, typescript-typings

I got following error

```
error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-native-camera'. '/Users/ilja/Documents/Repositories/blok/node_modules/react-native-camera/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/react-native-camera` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-native-camera';`
```

As a quick fix I created `typings/index.d.ts` (there is no @types/react-native-camera) file at root of my project and populated it with

```
declare module 'react-native-camera';
```

then, in my tsconfig file I added it to my type roots like this

```
"typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "./typings"],
```

however I am still getting same error when I build, leading me to think that my implementation is incorrect, what did I miss?

Edit, my full tsconfig looks like this

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es7"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "removeComments": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "./typings"],
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true
  },
  "exclude": ["./node_modules", "./android", "./ios", "./assets", "./__tests__", "./dist"],
  "include": ["./src"]
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `typeRoots` options specifies where to look for *packages* that may contain type information. The [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types) keeps saying that the compiler is looking for *packages*.

I've reproduced the structure you described and got the same error you did. Then I created a `react-native-camera` under `typings` and moved `index.d.ts` there so that I end up with this structure:

```
typings/
└── react-native-camera
    └── index.d.ts
```

With this structure, the compilation runs just fine.

Using a `typings` directory structure is fine, if you want that kind of structure. For some projects I use a `typings` directory. For other projects, I prefer something simpler: a `.d.ts` file in the source tree that declares everything that needs declaring. So if I start from the description you give, but dump `typings` and instead add `src/definitions.d.ts` containing

```
declare module 'react-native-camera';
```

then the code compiles just fine.

It is really a matter of preference what to use. Usually when a project becomes so complex that `src/definitions.d.ts` ends up being difficult to manage or hard to understand, I move to using a `typings` directory.

Comment: I would prefer to name this file `src/globals.d.ts` or `src/ambient.d.ts` because a project will likely grow to contain other "definitions" such as augmentations and perhaps declarations for REST interfaces, etc. Otherwise, excellent answer. +1

Comment: I did as you, but then I got an error for this line`import Camera from "react-native-camera"`: `Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'Camera'.`. What can I do to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

From [flowtype document](https://flow.org/en/docs/libdefs/), of library definitions section, it said:

> A libdef is a special file that informs Flow about the type signature
>   of some specific third-party module or package of modules that your
>   application uses. If you’re familiar with languages that have header
>   files (like C++), you can think of libdefs as a similar concept.
>
> ### General Best Practices
>
> Try to provide a libdef for each third-party library your project uses.

Look into *.flowconfig* in the root path, you will see it already defined there.

```
[libs]
node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-interface.js
node_modules/react-native/flow
./libdefs.js
```

And then look for *libdefs.js* in the root path, it should be there. Or just create it on your own.

For every module, declare it like below. Take `rxjs` for example:

```
declare module 'rxjs' { declare var exports: any; }
```

It's the official suggestion way, no *index.d.ts* modify needed.

Comment: Useful for flowtype users but not applicable to this question. The suggested definition style would result in a compilation error in TypeScript complaining about  `'rxjs'` not exporting whatever you might try to import from it