# React import a module with a declared namespace

Tags: reactjs, typescript-typings

I'm trying to figure out how I can use some existing functions in my React app.

There is a javascript file called Foo.js and and associated typing Foo.d.ts

Foo.js has many functions and at the top I see

```
//I don't understand what the below lines re doing
var A = A || {};
A.B= A.B|| {};
A.B.C= A.B.C|| {};
A.B.C.Foo= A.B.C.Foo|| {};

(function ()
 //here there are many functions
)();
```

Then in the d.ts file

```
declare namespace A.B.C.Foo
{
   //here there are exported functions
}
```

Now I have my react components in another folder, and I wish to use the functions defined in the Foo.js file. How do I use them?
I've tried adding the below to my component

```
///<reference path="../../../typings/@Test/Foo.d.ts" />
```

My component looks like below

```
const Component: React.FunctionComponent<IProps> = (props:Iprops) =>
{
  //I'm trying to use the function here.
}
```

What do I need to do to import the functions? I have no idea how to proceed.

Edit: One more piece of information:
In the html file I have a reference to Foo.js added in a script tag

" />

Edit: So I was able to get this to work. The accepted answer pointed me in the right direction with using global. Looks like Foo.js was already declared in a manner that the functions were available in React already. 

On the react side, adding the below reference path worked. To get type checking what I was missing was that that the .d.ts file exports a namespace so I had to prefix all functions with that namespace like so: A.B.C.Foo.FunctionName()

///

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to expose functions to the other modules of your application is when a module provides a `export` statement:

```js
// Foo.js
export const mySpecialFunction = () => {}
// otherFile.js
import { mySpecialFunction } from './Foo.js';
mySpecialFunction();
```

Otherwise, you will need to rely on `window` (considering your code runs on browser) to expose you function globally by import `Foo.js` somewhere (preferably on your app's entrypoint) and using the function:

```js
// Foo.js
window.mySpecialFunction = () => {}
// index.js (entrypoint of your app)
import './Foo.js';
// otherFile.js
mySpecialFunction();
```

But about Typescript, you can't just define a namespace. It must match with a path alias you define on `tsconfig.js` which points to `Foo.js`.

The fact is that isn't clear what you are aiming.

Edit:

> How would I do this "typescript as a global module attached to window"?

You could follow this documentation https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-d-ts.html. It will help you to define a global function or namespace.
Disclaimer: In a general way, do not rely on global modules as they decrease the code readibility.

Comment: That's the good answer if the foo functions were created by him, but I suspected he got them from an imported library.

Comment: So in the html file I have a reference to Foo.js added in a script tag
<script src="<path to Foo.js>" />

With that in mind, does that change anything? I'm guessing with the script tag added, I won't need to explicitky import right?

Comment: You are right, but using script let your import too much implicity. But if you are not in control you Foo.js you can do that.

Comment: Then you would declare the contents of Foo.js in your typescript as a global module attached to window.

Comment: How would I do this "typescript as a global module attached to window"?
Thanks for all the info so far!

Comment: This link worked for me if the library does not export the typescript types which is not often: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47573360/correct-way-to-handle-undefined-declaration-files-index-d-ts.

You can also use  a the typescript interface to type yourself what is exported from the library.

Answer (score 0):

Normally for a well formed library with exported functions you should add:

```
import FooFunctions from "A.B.C.Foo"
```

in your component, and then call the functions with FooFunction.{theFunctionYouWantToCall}(). You can also use this format of import:

```
import {theMatchingFunctionYouWantToCall} from "A.B.C.Foo"
```

Note: that's the normal scenario if you imported the library from npm, and it is in your node_modules. If you created this library or created the missing .d.ts file for it, make sure that Typescript is finding your .d.ts first.